# PostgreSQL function gen_random_uuid() not working

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I get `function get_random_uuid() does not exist` error when running this SQL:

`ALTER TABLE "posts" ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()`

I can see `pgcrypto` module listed in this query `select * from pg_available_extensions;`. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Is the extension loaded into schema public or another one?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Firstly, it's `gen_random_uuid()`, not `get_random_uuid()`

Comment: @CarlosMartinez, `gen..`, not `get..`

Answer (score 145):

You need to load the pgcrypto extension in the current database/schema with

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

like this (tested with PostgreSQL 12):

```
# SELECT gen_random_uuid();
ERROR:  function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
LINE 1: select gen_random_uuid();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
# CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION
# SELECT gen_random_uuid();
           gen_random_uuid            
--------------------------------------
 19a12b49-a57a-4f1e-8e66-152be08e6165
(1 row)
```

Comment: i added this , but  nothing has changed

Comment: `gen_random_uuid()` is in the Extension `pgcrypto`. So you will need to load this extension in the database you are working. `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto` does that. 
This is a perfect solution

Comment: First make sure you're connected to the database before running this, if it still doesn't work you may need to specify the schema: `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto WITH SCHEMA public`

Comment: If it doesn't work make sure you are connected to the right database (not just database server). It makes a difference.

Answer (score 14):

if you want to access **gen_random_uuid()** or any uuid type spesific database in the PostgreSQL you have to define **public** instance name! if you can't find **public** instance name you can select pgcrypto -> Properties -> Definition

```
public.gen_random_uuid()
```

if you use in schema.prisma you can use like this

```
@id @default(dbgenerated("public.uuid_generate_v4()"))
```

Comment: Upvoting because this response solved something I was totally stumped on. I'd switched my search_path, and suddenly lost access to `gen_random_uuid`, which I'd had seconds before. This made everything make sense!

Answer (score 4):

What helped for me was changing postgres version 12 to version 13.

`gen_random_uuid()` was added to the main distribution with Postgres 13. You can check the Postgres version with `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 2):

Found that the "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;" returns error like:

```
ERROR:   could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/pgcrypto.control": No such file or directory
```

The solution is to install postgresql-contrib package to fix it

found solution on: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242968/how-to-install-pgcrypto

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternate, You can use uuid_generate_v4() function instead of gen_random_uuid(); to generate random/dynamic UUID in postgres

```
select (uuid_generate_v4());
```

For more detail, you can refer: [uuid_generate_v4](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-uuid/)

Answer (score 1):

For people looking for solution in [Kysely](https://kysely.dev/)

Based on [okket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35960732/12555423)'s suggestion, you should add the following code to the first line of you `up` function in your migration:

```
await sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto`.execute(db)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
table.uuid('id').primary().unique().defaultTo(knex.raw('gen_random_uuid()'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply